# pregunta si o no en ruby

Tags: ruby

estoy haciendo un mini juego en ruby quiero hacer que cuando la persona responda si, vuela a ejecutarse el juego

ejem:

```
print "¿Desea volver a jugar si o no: " 
respuesta = gets.chomp
```

como hago para que cuando responda si, se repita el juego?

Comment: Te haces un ciclo

Comment: Deberías compartir todo lo que has intentado, planteando dudas concretas sobre dónde te has bloqueado y no has podido avanzar. Pedir directamente que te resuelvan un problema sin más no es la manera correcta de proceder.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar cualquier *loop* (o ciclo) para lograrlo, por ejemplo, utilizando `while`:

```
respuesta = "si"

while respuesta == "si" do
  print "¿Desea volver a jugar si o no: " 
  respuesta = gets.chomp
end
```

Este código genera una variable `respuesta` con valor inicial `"si"` para entrar en el ciclo `while`, una vez adentro la pregunta `"¿Desea volver a jugar si o no: "` se imprimirá una y otra vez hasta que el usuario escriba la palabra `"no"`.

Es importante destacar que con cualquier otro valor que escriba el usuario (diferente a `"si"`), el juego terminará (si quieres que sea al revés, es decir, que el juego siga a menos que escriba `"no"`, utiliza `until respuesta == "no"`).

Comment: Gracias amigo si me funciono

Comment: @JenselStivenGranobles Excelente! Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada (dando clic en la paloma). Suerte!